# Method as a parameter type

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I going over and trying to learn JavaScript from Objective-C, and I'm curious if having a method has a parameter type is possible in Objective-C. Below is an example of the findIndex() JavaStript function that takes a returns the index of the first element in an array that pass a test (provided as a function). What would an Objective-C implementation of this look like with blocks, if this is even possible?

If I am writing a class category on NSArray, how would I pass in a block to a method and execute that condition on itself (NSArray). If it's not possible, I'd love to know why.

```
    var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];

    function checkAdult(age) {
        return age >= 18;
    }

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.findIndex(checkAdult);
    }
```

Here is one helpful tidbit I found on another StackOverFlow question that might help with the block syntax. A the definition of the findIndex() function that I'm trying to implement.

**Block Syntax**

1. Block as a method parameter
   Template

   ```
   - (void)aMethodWithBlock:(returnType (^)(parameters))blockName {
           // your code
   }
   ```

   Example

   ```
   -(void) saveWithCompletionBlock: (void (^)(NSArray *elements, NSError *error))completionBlock{
           // your code
   }
   ```
2. Block as a method argument
   Template

   ```
   [anObject aMethodWithBlock: ^returnType (parameters) {
       // your code
   }];
   ```

   Example

   ```
   [self saveWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
       // your code
   }];
   ```
3. Block as a local variable**
   Template

   ```
   returnType (^blockName)(parameters) = ^returnType(parameters) {
       // your code
   };
   ```

   Example

   ```
   void (^completionBlock) (NSArray *array, NSError *error) = ^void(NSArray *array, NSError *error){
       // your code
   };
   ```
4. Block as a typedef
   Template

   ```
   typedef returnType (^typeName)(parameters);

   typeName blockName = ^(parameters) {
       // your code
   }
   ```

**`FindIndex()` Definition**

`Array.prototype.findIndex ( predicate [ , thisArg ] )`

> NOTE predicate should be a function that accepts three arguments and
>   returns a value that is coercible to the Boolean value true or false.
>   findIndex calls predicate once for each element of the array, in
>   ascending order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If
>   such an element is found, findIndex immediately returns the index of
>   that element value. Otherwise, findIndex returns -1.

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding code in Objective-C:

```
@implementation NSArray (MyExtension)

- (NSUInteger)findIndexWithPredicate:(BOOL (^)(id element, NSUInteger index, NSArray* array))predicate {
    NSUInteger result = NSNotFound;
    if (NULL != predicate) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.count; i++) {
            if (predicate(self[i], i, self)) {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@end
```

Note that I've changed default return value from `-1` to `NSNotFound`, because index is unsigned.

Method call:

```
NSUInteger index = [@[@3, @10, @18, @20] findIndexWithPredicate:^BOOL(id element, NSUInteger index, NSArray *array) {
    return [element integerValue] >= 18;
}];
```

You can avoid extra parameters, defined in JavaScript first index:

```
@implementation NSArray (MyExtension)

- (NSUInteger)findIndexWithPredicate:(BOOL (^)(id element))predicate {
    NSUInteger result = NSNotFound;
    if (NULL != predicate) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.count; i++) {
            if (predicate(self[i])) {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@end

NSUInteger index = [@[@3, @10, @18, @20] findIndexWithPredicate:^BOOL(id element) {
    return [element integerValue] >= 18;
}];
```

You can achieve same result without writing custom category, using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method:

```
[@[@3, @10, @18, @20] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([obj integerValue] >= 18) {
        *stop = YES;
        index = idx;
    }
}];
```

Also, it's possible to use alternatives to blocks, like C function pointers. But blocks give much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I did work out a similar solution to Boris:

```
NSArray *ages = @[@"3", @"10", @"18", @"20"];

BOOL(^parameter)(NSInteger integer) = ^BOOL(NSInteger integer) {

    if (integer >= 18) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
};

NSInteger(^block)(BOOL(^parameter)(), NSArray *array) = ^NSInteger(BOOL(^parameter)(), NSArray *array) {

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        NSInteger arrayInteger = [array[i] intValue];

        if (parameter(arrayInteger) == YES) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
};

NSInteger result = block(parameter, ages);
```